# Theme broken Suddnly wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi I am using my listing theme in wordpress.

But it stopped working suddenly today, even yesterday it was working fine.

```
 Class 'Elementor\PageSettings\Manager' not found in /home/urgluubo/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-listing-child/includes/filters.php on line 261
```

Can you please gude what happen to it, should I contact to theme support.

Please help iam in trouble.

Comment: There is some issue with your child theme. Try switching back to parent theme

Comment: its says same issue with parent as well

Comment: Have you recently installed any plugins or added any codes to functions.php ?

Comment: no i ahve even disabled all plugin and i did not add any code in function.php

Comment: just change theme to storefront and check if issue still persists

Comment: Other thems works the issue with only my listing theme I am realy in trouble

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190934/discussion-between-sunil-rawat-and-melvin).